# Free shipping on google checkout in magento

Tags: magento, google-checkout

I am using magento 1.7.0.2 and Google Checkout. When want to use Flat rate, Free Shipping over $75 and 10% shipping between $68 - $75.

How i  implement all three on my magento store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have searched more and got a solution, it's not a good idea to change core file but it's working. You can calculate price with charges before sending in google checkout. change core file of google checkout at ***/app/code/core/Mage/GoogleCheckout/Model/Api/Xml/checkout.php*** .

***Go to line 579*** and make condition as you want. In my case the condition is as:

```
*********************

$subTotal = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getSubtotal();
            if($subTotal <=68.50){

            $xml .= <<<EOT
                <{$nodeName} name="{$title}">
                    <shipping-restrictions>
                        <allowed-areas>
                        {$allowedAreasXml}
                        </allowed-areas>
                    </shipping-restrictions>
                    <price currency="{$this->getCurrency()}">{$price}</price>
                </{$nodeName}>
EOT;
            }

            if(($subTotal > 68.50) && ($subTotal < 75)){
            $price = $subTotal*10/100;
            $xml .= <<<EOT
                <{$nodeName} name="{$title}">
                    <shipping-restrictions>
                        <allowed-areas>
                        {$allowedAreasXml}
                        </allowed-areas>
                    </shipping-restrictions>
                    <price currency="{$this->getCurrency()}">{$price}</price>
                </{$nodeName}>
EOT;
            }

            if($subTotal >=75){
            $price = 0.00;
            $xml .= <<<EOT
                <{$nodeName} name="{$title}">
                    <shipping-restrictions>
                        <allowed-areas>
                        {$allowedAreasXml}
                        </allowed-areas>
                    </shipping-restrictions>
                    <price currency="{$this->getCurrency()}">{$price}</price>
                </{$nodeName}>
EOT;
            }
        }
```

---

Now refresh your store and make payment with google checkout.